# want to submit ajax form on Enter Key for a4j button in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

I have an ajax form with a a4j:commandbutton. I want to submit the form on press of Enter key.
I am using onkeypress on the commandbutton to check the enter key press.
The script is called properly and after the keycode =13 check, the form doesnt get submitted.
It gets submitted only if I use an alert box.

I know as I am using ajax, it needs some delay to process, so that is done using the alert box. But if I want it to submit without the alert box?? how to do that?

Code snippet:
function submitOnEnter(e)
        {

```
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;
        else return true;

    if (keycode ==13)
    {
    var form =#{rich:element('loginform:submituser')};
    alert('in alert'+form.click()); // this works and form gets submitted
            //form.click(); // i want this to work.
    return false;
    }
 else
    return true;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use richfaces hotkey functionality for achieving this.What I can fathom is that you want to submit a form using Enter key. If my assumtion is right , then use following code

```
<rich:hotKey key="return"
         handler="#{rich:element('Form_Name')}.submit()" 
         selector="#Form_Name"/>
```